# wp_localized_script is not defined when called via jquey ajax

Tags: wp-localize-script

I am struggling to get my ajax request to work. It fails when I fire my `$ajax` and I get this error...

**Uncaught ReferenceError: feature_ajax is not defined**

This is my `functions.php`

```
// load our frontend modifiers
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/Frontend.lib.php');
```

This is my `Frontend.lib.php` class php...

```
class Frontend
{

    /** frontend constructor */
    public function __construct()
    {

        // enqueue our scripts
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'action_wp_enqueue_scripts'));

        // add out ajax actions
        $this->ajax_actions();

    }

    /** frontend enqueued scripts */
    public function action_wp_enqueue_scripts()
    {

        // localize admin ajax
        wp_localize_script('ajax-actions', 'ajax_actions', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ));

        // enqueue scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax-actions');

    }


    /** ajax actions */
    public function ajax_actions()
    {

        // admin field postdata ajax actions
        add_action('wp_ajax_field_postdata', [__CLASS__, 'field_postdata']);

        // public field postdata ajax actions
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_field_postdata', [__CLASS__, 'field_postdata']);

    }

    // Field Post Data
    public static function field_postdata()
    {
        global $post;
        $post_id = ($_REQUEST['id']);

        if($post_id){
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            setup_postdata($post);
            get_template_part('ajax/modal','field');
            die();
        }

    }

}

new Frontend();
```

When I fire the `$ajax` script below, this is when I get the error *feature_ajax is not defined*.

But it is defined in the code above.

This script below is my `theme-min.js` file

```
// load feature post data
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    timeout: 8000,
    url: ajax_actions.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'field_postdata',
        id: post_id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Any help in understanding what i'm doing wrong would be great.

Thanks

---

**Updated Fixed Code**

So what I changed to make this work. I was already enqueuing my `main-min.js` file, so I combined my `wp_localize_script` using the same handle as my enqueued javascript and it worked.

```
// register js in footer
$filename = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/main-min.js';
wp_register_script('main-js', $filename, array(), rand(), true);

// localize theme-js ajax actions
wp_localize_script('main-js', 'ajax_actions', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));

// enqueue required scripts
wp_enqueue_script('main-js')
```

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead? It's much easier to debug, and more straightforward to register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To successfully add variable to the `window` object via `wp_localize_script` you need to properly invoke three functions in the following sequence:

1. [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)
2. [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)
3. [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

In your case you're missing the `wp_register_script`. In case someone experiences the same issue, follow the code procedures below.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    function my_theme_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
        $handle = 'my_handle';

        // Register the script
        wp_register_script($handle, '/path/to/my_script.js');

        // Localize the script with a new data
        wp_localize_script($handle, 'object_name', [
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ]);

        // Enqueue the script
        wp_enqueeu_script($handle);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Then, you can access the localized object in **Javascript**

```
var ajax_url = object_name.ajax_url;
console.log(ajax_url);
```

Change the `$handle` variable content as well as the `object_name` in **PHP** that makes sense to your application.

Comment: Ahhh i see i was already `wp_register_script('theme-js', ...)` so i've just done this now `wp_localize_script('theme-js', ... )` and it works now thank you dude